# how to configure the dart sdk version in flutter in github actions

Tags: flutter

Now I am configure the flutter project like this in github actions:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        flutter-version: '1.22.5'
    - name: Select Xcode version
      run: sudo xcode-select -s '/Applications/Xcode_12.1.app/Contents/Developer'
    - name: Bundle install
      run: cd ./ios && bundle install && bundle update fastlane
    - name: Install tools
      run: |
       flutter pub get
       cd ./ios && pod install
```

but it shows like this:

```
ERR : The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.4.
    | 
    | Because Cruise depends on intl >=0.17.0-nullsafety which requires SDK version >=2.11.0-180.0.dev <3.0.0, version solving failed.
FINE: Exception type: SolveFailure
FINE: package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 312:5   VersionSolver._resolveConflict
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 133:27  VersionSolver._propagate
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 97:11   VersionSolver.solve.<fn>
```

I know the dart version when compile in github actions is too low, what should I do to specify dart version? when i using the intl lower version of package:

```
  intl: 0.16.1
```

show error like this when compile project:

```
"zh_HK": 42 untranslated message(s).
"zh_TW": 42 untranslated message(s).
"zu": 42 untranslated message(s).
To see a detailed report, use the untranslated-messages-file 
option in the l10n.yaml file:
untranslated-messages-file: desiredFileName.txt
<other option>: <other selection> 


This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that 
need to be translated.
Running "flutter pub get" in cruise-open...
Because Cruise depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 is required.
So, because Cruise depends on intl 0.16.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because Cruise depends on intl 0.16.1, version solving failed.)
```

what should I do to solve this conflict problem?

Comment: show debug log outputs. what does `subosito/flutter-action@v1` output?

Comment: this is my full log output `https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open/runs/1708879046?check_suite_focus=true`. @ch271828n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, flutter 1.22.5 does come with dart 2.10.4. For example, I install this version on my own computer, and I do see the dart packaged with it is 2.10.4.

Therefore, you need to change your dependency on the `Cruise`, maybe to an older version.

Or, you may need to use the `beta` channel of Flutter:

```
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '1.20.5'
          channel: 'beta'
```

Comment: I must using the `intl >=0.17.0-nullsafety` because the international of my app need this package.

Comment: @Dolphin what about lower version of intl

Comment: could I specify the dart sdk version seperate?

Comment: @Dolphin IMHO that github action does *not* allow so

Comment: that may be quite unstable! try not to do that

Comment: lower version of intl make the project could not compile, it give me tips must upgrade the intl package. @ch271828n

Comment: Conclusion: use `0.16.0` for `intl`. Your 0.17 is *prerelease* which is also unstable.

Comment: Because Cruise depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 is required.
So, because Cruise depends on intl 0.16.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because Cruise depends on intl 0.16.1, version solving failed.)

Comment: @Dolphin edit the question, and put *full* error. I will read it tomorrow.

Comment: look at this and follow it https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages

Comment: very strange. how do you run it on your own machine